# React - Axiost put request get weird result

Tags: reactjs, axios, put

I am working on my project with a backend.
and currently working on a component which performs a `put` request to update details of a `customer` bean. however, I am experiencing a weird behavior.

**Component:**

```
function UpdateCustomer(props): JSX.Element {
    
    const history = useHistory();
    const [skipCount, setSkipCount] = useState(true);
    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
    const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    
    async function formData() {
  
      try {
        const response = await axios.put<CustomerModel>(globals.adminUrls.updateCustomer + props.location.state.id, {
          firstName: firstName,
          LastName: lastName,
          email: email,
          password: password
        });
  
        const updated = response.data;
        store.dispatch(customerUpdatedAction(updated));
        notify.success(CUSTOMER_SccMsg.CUSTOMER_UPDATED)
  
      }
      catch (err) {
        notify.error(err);
      }
    }
  
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      formData();
    }
  
    useEffect(() => {
      if (skipCount) setSkipCount(false);
      if (!skipCount) formData();
  
    }, []);
  
    return (
      <div className="custom-field">
        <h2>Update Customer</h2>
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
              
            <label>First name</label>
            <input type="text" name="firstName" onChange={(e) => { setFirstName(e.target.value) }} />
            <label>Last name</label>
            <input type="text" name="lastName" onChange={(e) => { setLastName(e.target.value) }} />
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" onChange={(e) => { setEmail(e.target.value) }} />
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="text" name="password" onChange={(e) => { setPassword(e.target.value) }} />
  
            <input type="submit" name="submit" />
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
export default UpdateCustomer;
```

**backend Service:**

```
public void updateCustomer(@Valid int id, CustomerDto customerDto) throws  DoesNotExistException {

        Customer customerDao = customerMapper.toDao(customerDto);

        if (!custRepo.existsById(id))
            throw new DoesNotExistException("Customer does not exist");

        custRepo.saveAndFlush(customerDao);
```

**backend Controller:**

```
  @PutMapping(value = "update/customer/{id}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
    @Override
    public void updateCustomer(@PathVariable int id, @RequestBody CustomerDto customerDto) throws DoesNotExistException {
        adminService.updateCustomer(id, customerDto);
    }
```

**Result I am getting:**

1. I am able to save all fields into a const apart from `lastName` for some reason. it behaves exactly like the other fields. however, this specific field sends `null` to server while other fields send the input values.
2. Instead of performing an `update` to bean it just `adds` this as a seperate bean.

**Why is this weird?**

I have an identical component for updating a company and it seems to work just fine. why does this component behave differently?

Hope someone can put a hand on the problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put LastName in the request body, check below image:

[image]

I think there is a mistake here, it looks like should be `lastName`, not `LastName`.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that, it fixed one of my problems. however, can you see why it reacts as `post` instead of `put`?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. I think you should test your back-end (with Postman or cURL) to see your back-end working expected or not. Then you can move forward, maybe React working well but your back-end not working as expected.

Comment: I Solved my issue, however, since your eyes were sharp on the other issue I will mark this as correct answer. good day sir.